# Home-hosting ¿Se puede?

Tags: servidor, redes

Que tal,

Tengo una Aplicación que he estado comercializando y desarrollando por cerca de 10 años.
Actualmente uso VPS en Digital Ocean, Azure y Hostinger; sin embargo las prestaciones están creciendo y los requerimientos del sistema han ido creciendo en versiones nuevas.
Tratando de no encarecer los costos a los clientes ya que en su mayoría son de apoyo a sectores marginados, estoy buscando opciones, entre ellas crear mi propio hosting.

Actualmente uso vps, en una o varias, así que el controlador del dominio me redirige a una IP y estas a su vez a través de vhost me indican si el sitio se trata de sub1.domain.com => IP1 o sub2.domain.com => IP2, sin problemas.

Ahora quiero hacer un self hosting sencillo para ir  probando, quiero contratar el plus de no-ip.com para tener varios subdominios, solo que de momento solo he tenido experiencias configurando una sola ip dinámica por servidor.
Lo que intento hacer es algo similar a esto (sin usar controlador de dominio interno):
[image: Idea de Concepto]

1. Que el sub1.domain.com resuelva a través de no-ip a la ip dinámica
   x.x.x.x puerto 8080.
2. Que el sub2.domain.com resuelva a través de
   no-ip a la ip dinámica x.x.x.x puerto 8081.

Mis preguntas concretas :

**Es posible? Si no, ¿De que otra manera sin contratar una IP Fija?.
¿Alguien ha tenido experiencia en hacer algo similar?.**

Estoy pensando contratar Axtel simétrico de 30MBS para empezar.

Gracias.

Comment: yo he adquirido un plan en [https://www.lea.mx
](https://www.lea.mx) cual es la diferencia principal entre un home hosting y uno pago? quiero ver si puedo avaratar costos pero tambien ver si esto es recomendable..

Comment: Podría agregarle más capacidad de procesamiento, por ejemplo : La BD requiere al menos 4GB de RAM para trabajar sin problemas y eso sería barato de implementar en un self hosting ya que tengo los servidores.